# Extending ImageInput with custom onDrop behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Is it possible to extend the `react-admin`'s `ImageInput` component to have my custom behaviour?

```js
class CustomImageInput extends ImageInput {
    onDrop = files => {
        console.log(files)
        // custom image upload ...
    };
}
```

However it keeps throwing `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`.

May I know if components provided by react-admin are intended to be inherited or actually not?

Comment: In general, the React team recommends against inheritance - https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: @ChrisSandvik Ok, thanks for the hint. I will try for composition.